# Weird shading when rendered compared to preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

Hi im trying to render a downlight and the rendered results gives me with this weird artifact/bug? In preview mode everything looks fine. Rendering it from the side is no problem. the problem only occurs in this angle looking at the cone.
Tried to make a new blend file and imported the object but still the same issue.
Normals looks fine.
This is the first time i encounter this kind of problem and im clueless.

EDIT:
I think i have narrowed it down to a resolution issue. Rendering it higher than 2000x2000 the artifacts starts to appear. Im really bad what best practice is when it comes to resolution and if the resolution ration has something to do with it.

[image: Rendered result]

[image: Preview]

Comment: check if your blender scene has objects that are not visible in the viewport but visible in the render

Comment: Hi, i only have 4 things in the scene. Camera, sphere for background, the object and a sun. but I just discovered something.. I think the render resolution has something to do with it. it seems when i go higher than 2000x2000 it starts to give me these artifacts. it hasnt been a problem before and i dont know how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe just share your file here using [blender-exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) so that we can see for ourselves.